# In PHP's Gender\Gender class, what is the difference between IS_UNISEX_NAME and IS_A_COUPLE?

Tags: php, pecl

I was looking at [the Gender class usage example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gender.example.admin.php), which contains this snippet:

```
case Gender::IS_UNISEX_NAME:
    printf("The name %s is unisex in %s\n", $name, $data['country']);
break;


case Gender::IS_A_COUPLE:
    printf("The name %s is both male and female in %s\n", $name, $data['country']);
break;
```

That gives me the impression that `IS_UNISEX_NAME` and `IS_A_COUPLE` are the same thing, which makes me wonder why there are two different constants for it.

It also makes me think that it could be due to a historical reason. Or maybe it's just an oversight.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an example that isn't related to programming.

Comment: @DanielA.White: I disagree. That "example" is the only documentation of the meaning of these constants, so the question is about the meaning of the constants in the `Gender` library.

Comment: The library seems to built on the original owner's determination.  You might need to contact Joerg Michael (as the writer of the original C code) or Anatol Belski (as the owner of the pecl distribution) to find out how they made the distinctions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took [aynber's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089675/in-phps-gender-gender-class-what-is-the-difference-between-is-unisex-name-and#comment26478916_18089675) and emailed Anatol Belski, the current maintainer of the [Gender extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/gender). Here's his response (published with his permission):

> Basically that's the same thing. In PHP 'is couple' is done almost for
>   the compatibility reasons, as nothing blocks one to change the name
>   dictionary. Defining same forename as male and female (so two lines)
>   means couple. Using '?' means it being unisex. The terms how they're
>   meant - couple is a name common to both male and female, unisex could be
>   for example a female name given to male person. With the default dataset
>   you can simply join that two cases in the switch. For the database
>   format just look into data/nam_dict.txt in the package.